# Can't see the other div move

Tags: firebase

I decided to work on a very basic multiplayer game. 
At the moment, I've successfully managed to get the presence-detection to work and when a new user logs in, his div appears on the initial screen, but that's about it. 
I wanted to know if I needed to update the position of each div every time they move and have that store in Firebase? Here's currently what  I have to append the div when a user logs in:

```
 presence.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var online = snapshot.numChildren();
        $('#online').html(online + ' online.');
        $('#game').append('<div class="'+ uid +'" id="character"></div>');
    })
```

I decided to also give each div a specific uid to differentiate them. 
If you take a look at my code below I also included a basic movement system.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gk9cm6t9/2/

I hope that someone can help me out with this,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all players need to know where all players are, then yes you will need to synchronize the position across all players. But whether that is needed for your game is something only you can decide. Unless you clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish and where you got stuck, I will vote to close this question as unclear.

Comment: I just don't understand the logic behind it, and where I should go from what I have to achieve my goal: getting a div to move around and show up on another user's screen. I spent a good amount of my time looking for multiplayer tutorials like this, but I haven't found anything close to what I am trying to achieve, even though it should be simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your fiddle currently does two things:

1. listen for users/players being present in the chatroom
2. move a box around the screen when you use the cursor keys

But the two pieces of code currently seem completely unrelated. To make this a multiplayer game, you will have to send the coordinates where each user's box is to the other players. Luckily this is something that Firebase excels at.

Say that you have a data structure like this:

```
positions
   uid1: { x: 100, y: 150 }
   uid2: { x:  25, y: 200 }
```

Each player could simply listen for all the positions and draw the boxes in the correct location. Each player can also handle the keyboard and update their position in Firebase. This will then loop back and notify all players.

So these are the steps you'll need to take:

1. update the player's position in Firebase in your keyboard handling
2. draw all player boxes whenever something changes

You already have keyboard handling code, so all you need to do is add code to store the new location in Firebase.

```
var myPositionRef = firebaseRef.child('positions').child(uid);

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
      $('#character').stop().animate({
        left: '-=10'
      }); //left arrow key
      myPositionRef.transaction(function(currentPosition) {
        if (currentPosition) {
          currentPosition.x -= 10;
        }
        else {
          currentPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        }
        return currentPosition;
      });
      break;
    ...
  }
```

There are probably dozens of other/simpler ways to do this, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I've got one more question! http://jsfiddle.net/gk9cm6t9/5/ why am I getting a "cannot read property x of undefined" when trying to update the position

Comment: My code was meant as a general outline of how to do this, not as a working example. If you get an error like that, set a breakpoint in your browser's debugger and step through the code, inspecting variables with every step. Doing that will teach you more than copy/pasting code from various places.

Comment: It's your own code that causes the error btw: clicking on the error message in Chrome's JavaScript console takes me to `console.log(firebaseRef.myPositionRef.x);`

Comment: yes I know that that's it, but why is it giving me an error? Is the `firebaseRef.myPositionRef.x` not referenced correctly?

Comment: I did use your code as an outline and it works great, it's just the second step that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: A Firebase ref does not **contain** the value of your object, since that object might not be loaded from the server yet. Please follow this tutorial before continuing: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted It's advertised to take 5 minutes and will save you a lot of time and headaches. The answer to your last question comes around step 6.

Comment: I went through the tutorial and came up with this code: `myPositionRef.on('child_added', function(currentPosition) {
        $('.'+uid).css('left',currentPosition.x);
        $('.'+uid).css('top',currentPosition.y);
   });` shouldn't that work? or would I need to update everything every time the player moves

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63518/discussion-between-frank-van-puffelen-and-nottobrag).